# Webstorm Projects and Node - What to Share and Why

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I've got an idea folder in my Webstorm project.  This is a node app.  What do I need to share and why from this folder in source control?  What settings should I share and why?

Also, how do I retain all my preferences from project to project?  I find that if I create a new project  (which I do by simply opening webstorm then opening the folder of code I just cloned down from a repo), I have to reset stuff like the JS version, and a bunch of other stuff in Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You just need to add the source folder to source control.

2) The easiest way to share Webstorm code style setting is using the [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) plugin and adding the file to source control:
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-code-style.html#d649738e184